# Editing collada file with built-in UVs

Tags: texturing, uv, unity, uv-image-editor

I recently purchased some basic terrain assets, and when I import them to Unity, they look nicely textured.

[image: Textured Mesh in Unity]

My plan is to create several variations on this terrain (creating paths etc.) and I figured it would be a matter of importing them into Blender, then painting it, or exporting the UVs and creating a texture in Photoshop or something.

However, when I import the .dae file into Blender, all I get is a grey, untextured version of the mesh.  I can see there's a UV map listed in the file, but I have no idea how I'd go about accessing it or editing it.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look Honestly because i would post a comment but because i don't have enough rep i have to answer, but with blender try to go into the material properties and hopefully if you got the mesh of the internet it should have different materials, just change those separate materials and modify them to suit you since they should of been already made from the owner.

[image: Where the materials should appear]

As seen above, there should be multiple textures for that one model.

I hope this helps and i don't quite know if i completely answered your question. If you don't see the extra materials i would say it wasn't made to be compatible with blender.

Comment: Hey man, I think you really helped crack this!  I'll post a more complete answer below, but I wanted to say thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the guy above really helped me with this, but I just wanted to flesh out what all it was (in case anyone has a similar issue).

Sure enough, as he said, there were two materials listed in the material properties window.

[image: Material Properties Window]

However it was still frustrating because the image itself still looked to be one uniform texture.  However, if you modify those materials...

[image: Aha!]

Sure enough, a pattern starts to emerge.  I realize what (I think) these people are doing is setting the materials in Blender, but doing the actual coloring in Unity with a shader.

So I believe to modify one of these meshes, I'd just need to assign different materials to the different faces, and even though they wouldn't look different in Blender, in Unity they should show up as the proper color.  I'm not sure how exactly they're making the conversion from material to color (if let's say I wanted to create my own material with its own color properties) but I think this is at least a good jumping off point.

Comment: Hmm actually this didn't work... If I import it from Blender it comes in with that hot pink color.  If I try to replace it with the existing material in the project, it resets the texture to how it was before I put it in Blender... somehow that information of what material goes where is embedded somewhere else...